# Difference between window.confirm() and just confirm()

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `window.confirm()` and just `confirm()`? Similar for `alert()` and `prompt()`.

Do I need to write `window.` each time?

Comment: window. is not required, since confirm is a method on it's own and doesn't brosers know that window isn't required.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every "standalone" function is actually a method of the `window` object. Since the `window` object is the default context, it is always implicit. Calling `alert` or `window.alert` is the same.

Comment: Although you are right, not all frameworks like the notation without the `window.` in front of it. An example of such framework is Jasmine which creates Unit Tests.

Answer (score 1):

There is none, not in the actual function.

When you call `alert()` alone, the script first looks for a variable called `alert` in the current scope and calls it if it exists. Otherwise, it moves up the scope chain before finally reaching `window.alert` and calling that.

However, if you have code like this:

```
(function() {
   var alert = function(str) { /* my cool overlay popup function */ };
   // do stuff
   alert("Hello, World!"); // calls my custom overlay
   window.alert("Hello, World!"); // calls the native alert
})();
```

(That being said, I define my custom overlays as `Alert`, `Confirm` and a multi-purpose `Dialog`, to prevent confusion)

Answer (score 0):

Everything in JavaScript is objects and have methods, but `window` object is default, so if you call something like a function, you actually call method of `window`.

However it may be differences in case if you have your own function called the same as `window` object has.

Also it is even possible to shadow method and make it not to work, for example:

```
(function () {
    var alert;
    alert("Not working...");
})()
```